# can one python function argument depend on another argument?

Tags: python, function

I would like to have something like the following function:

```
calc_map(img_in, img_height, img_width, mapping = np.zeros((image_height, image_width)))
[function body]
```

apparently it is not possible that the default argument of mapping is depending on other arguments in that function.
Is there another way around that without using image_height and image_width as global?

I would imagine to put this in my function:

```
calc_map(img_in, img_height, img_width)
mapping = np.zeros((image_height, image_width))
[function body]
```

but I also need to put an already existing mapping into the function and not having overwritten it..

appreciate any help, regards, eli

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make the default `None` in the function signature, and then replace it inside the body with whatever you want:

```
def calc_map(img_in, img_height, img_width, mapping = None)
    if mapping is None:
        mapping = np.zeros((image_height, image_width))
```

Answer (score 0):

Make default value to `False` and check:

```
def calc_map(img_in, img_height, img_width, mapping = False)
    if not mapping:
        mapping = np.zeros((image_height, image_width))
```